# Invalid character value for cast specification vb.net MS Access to SQL Server import

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ms-access, insert

I have the following INSERT query in my program (the variables are being assigned a value from an Access database, and are being inserted into a new SQL Server database). The code runs through fine, the value in the `Parameters.Add` section are all what they should be, but when it gets to the line `sql.ExecuteNonQuery()` I get given the error

> Invalid character value for cast specification.
>      at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>      at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

```
        For Each dr As DataRow In getDataTable(sqlct, importsCon, Nothing).Rows

            Dim conID As Integer
            Dim custacc As String
            Dim datestart As Object
            Dim daterenew As Object
            Dim fee As Double
            Dim agree As String
            Dim details As String
            Dim datesent As Object
            Dim timesent As Object
            Dim remname As String
            Dim remmail As String

            conID = dr("ContractID")
            custacc = dbToString(dr("CustAcc"))
            datestart = dbToDate(dr("DateStart"))
            daterenew = dbToDate(dr("DateRenew"))
            fee = dr("Fee")
            agree = dbToString(dr("Agreement"))
            details = dbToString(dr("OtherDetails"))
            datesent = dbToDate(dr("DateSent"))
            timesent = dbToTime(dr("TimeSent"))
            remname = dbToString(dr("ReminderName"))
            remmail = dbToString(dr("ReminderEmail"))

            sql.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblContracts(ContractID, CustAcc, DateStart, DateRenew, Fee, Agreement, OtherDetails, DateSent, TimeSent, ReminderName, ReminderEmail) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
            sql.Transaction = tr
            sql.Parameters.Clear()
            sql.Parameters.Add("@ContractID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = conID
            sql.Parameters.Add("@CustAcc", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = custacc
            sql.Parameters.Add("@DateStart", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = datestart
            sql.Parameters.Add("@DateRenew", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = daterenew
            sql.Parameters.Add("@Fee", OleDbType.Double).Value = fee
            sql.Parameters.Add("@Agreement", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = agree
            sql.Parameters.Add("@OtherDetails", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = details
            sql.Parameters.Add("@DateSent", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = datesent
            sql.Parameters.Add("@TimeSent", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = timesent
            sql.Parameters.Add("@ReminderName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = remname
            sql.Parameters.Add("@ReminderEmail", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = remmail

            sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sql.Parameters.Clear()

        Next
```

What is the problem with my code? All of the datatypes match that of the database (Objects are datetime in the database, but they're initially objects as they go through another function first)

Comment: @GordThompson I changed all of the `OleDbType.VarChar` to `OleDbType.VarWChar`, the same error message appeared

Comment: In the INSERT query, start off just by doing `sql.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblContracts(ContractID) VALUES(?)` and then comment all parameter lines except conID. Test the program. If it works, add another in (CustAcc), and repeat the process until you find the one which is breaking it, to help narrow down the issue

Comment: @David Thanks, so the error is the line `sql.Parameters.Add("@DateSent", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = datesent`

Comment: Okay, good, so you know the line it's on... Tell me, what is the value that the query is trying to insert which causing the error?

Comment: @David The value is 12:00:00 AM, it was converted to this because it was a null in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discovered in the comments, the problem is on line  `sql.Parameters.Add("@DateSent", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = datesent`

Because the database you are importing is storing a null value in this field on one or more records, in the function that checks whether or not it is null, it's being converted from null to `12:00:00 AM` (this code is not given in the question, so I'm not sure why or how.

Now, you cannot insert `12:00:00 AM` as a `DBDate` value because, well, as it says on the tin, it wants a date format value (yyyyMMdd, or similar).

The solution to this problem is to simply change the aforementioned line to

```
sql.Parameters.Add("@DateSent", OleDbType.Date).Value = datesent
```

Using `OleDbType.Date` will not insert the value, even with no date being specified, as it able to work with this, and insert a default date for this method, which I believe is `1899-12-30`. But either way, this will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks David, this has solved it! I changed them all to Date just to avoid further hassle :)